# How to set maximum date in input type date IONIC 1 IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, ionic-v1

I get a problem to set maximum input type date in IONIC 1 IOS, and this is my script :

```
<input type="date" max="2018-04-03" required>
```

but it doesn't work, I have tried to search but fail all, please anyone help me to solve this problem because on thursday I must collect this duty.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29086764/set-min-date-to-current-date-in-angularjs-input?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I have tried it, but fail all, thanks @AnilKumarArya

Comment: @FrankAndrew please review an answer and please let me know whether it may help to you or not?